# Semiconductor: calculating effective carrier concentration

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, thermal-conductivity

In one of the derivations of the effective carrier concentration for a semiconductor, an equilibrium $$• \rightarrow e^- + h^+$$ is considered. In this case, $$ K_c = \frac{[e][h]}{[•]c^{\circ}} =  \frac{f_e f_h}{f_• c^\circ} \exp{(-E_g/kT)} $$, with $$f_{e} = f_{h} = 2(\frac{2\pi m^* k_B T}{h^2})^{3/2}  $$ and $$f_• = 1$$, where $f_e$ and $f_h$ are volume independent partition functions for the electron and the hole, assuming their effective masses are equal. In the derivations that I see online and in textbooks such as The Physics and Chemistry of Solids by S. Elliott, [•] is ignored or is effectively set to 1.

**I don't understand why this treatment of [•]  is valid and why [•] will not be the concentration of electrons in the valence band.**

Comment: So, having moved over from Chemistry SE, I'll ask: what do you mean by concentration of electrons in the valence band? Do you mean the density of states?

Comment: @JonCuster Sorry for a delayed response! No, I meant concentration, i.e. the number of electrons in a particular volume, or, alternatively, the "reactant" in the analogy with chemical equilibrium. However, I'm wondering if it's not just set to 1 because it's "chemical activity" tends to 1?

Comment: Concentration (electrons per unit volume) would not be the right way to think of it. The 'parent' states of the reaction are filled valence states, which should also be thought of in a density of states framework.

Comment: @JonCuster Ok, thanks, I see now, it would be density of states at the maximum energy in valence band – but I don't see how this helps answering the question?

Comment: So, you have a fixed pool of parent states. You can not change that number. You can make electron-hole pairs, but the population of available valence states does not change. In an activity framework, how can the coefficient be anything other than 1?

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, if turns out I didn't understand what an activity is then – this makes much more sense now, thank you!!

Comment: Do you think I need to delete this question, as it wouldn't be helpful for others?

Comment: No, not necessarily. It actually does keep coming up, with different sticking points for each person. I keep thinking I should write up something fairly comprehensive, yet finding the time is not easy...